# C# how to hide a form from another form

Tags: c#, .net

I am new in c# and i have a trouble with my app.

I Had 2 forms (1º and 2º) called Login and Checkuser, and i need to hide Login form when Checkuser checks a correctly login.

I tried with this from Checkuserform:

```
Login Loginform = new Login();
Loginform.Hide();
```

but it doesn't works, so i tried other way but i cant make it work.
i set a int on Login form called Hider = 0.
So, when checker checks a correctly user, the Hider will be 1, then in Login form when check the value of Hider and it is 1, the form will hide.

```
//In Login form
public int Hider = 0;
//Checker of Loginform constantly run so when hider change to 1, it should hide
if (Hider == 1) { this.Hide(); }

//In Checkuser form
//When user login correctly
Login Loginform = new Login();
Loginform.hider = 1;
```

But it doesn't work, the hider value continues with 0, it not change.
I had other code with strings values, but from Login to Checkuser and it works correctly, but when i try make the same with int but from Checkuser to Login (With the hider) it doesnt work.

I need help to fix this problem. And sorry for my english haha.
Thank you, regards.

Comment: Are you calling `Hide()`  during Form Load?

Comment: You are creating a new login form in your checkuser form and not showing it. It is not the login form that you have already open. You need to pass a reference to it to the Checkuser form.

Answer (score 1):

```
//In Login form
public int Hider = 0;
//Checker of Loginform constantly run so when hider change to 1, it should hide
if (Hider == 1) { Loginform.Hide(); }



//In Checkuser form
//When user login correctly
Login Loginform = new Login();
Loginform.hider = 1;
```

*`this`* function only talks about the context area in which it is defined , in this case login form and you are using it implicitly in checkuser form.
try changing  `this.Hide()` to `Loginform.Hide()` , hope it may now work.